# Checking cookies and setting session

Tags: php, session, cookies

i'm not a programer at all so i need some help wtih this situation:

I need to set cookies and sessions to a referal system that work like this:
www.mywebsite.com/?id=affiliate

1. i need to chek if affiliate exists in database.
2. if so to get username to set a cookie and name to print in page.
3. if not i i'll use a default affiliate such as number one affiliate.
   cookies must be valid for 30 days

one of my problems is when a refered customer comes to my website without **../?id=affiliate** in link, because i need to check if there's some cookie registered and if not to set a brand new cookie with default affiliate.

I've writed this code but i'm 110% sure that it's incorrect.
Could you please kindly take a look and give some suggestions. I appreciate.

**Code:**

```
$id = $_POST("id");
if ($_POST("id") = null) {
    if( isset( $_COOKIE['pro']  ) )   
    { 
        $id = $_COOKIE['pro']; 
    }else{
        $id = "defaultaffiliate"
    }
}
session_start();
$rs = mysql_query("select * from users where Username='$id'");
$arr=mysql_fetch_array($rs);
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0){
    $uid=$arr['id'];
    $_SESSION["name"]=$arr['Name'];
    setcookie("pro", $uid, time()+30 * 24 * 3600);
}else{
    $uid='claudioxerez';
    $_SESSION["name"]='Claudio Xerez';
    setcookie("pro", $uid, time()+30 * 24 * 3600);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Set Session and Cookie :

Config.php :

```
    $SERVER="localhost";
    $DB_NAME="********";
    $USERNAME="*******";
    $PASSWORD="*******";


$CONN=mysql_connect($SERVER,$USERNAME,$PASSWORD);
mysql_query("set names UTF8",$CONN);
if(!$CONN)
{
    die('ERROR IN CONNECT TO DATABASE!'.mysqli_connect_error());    
    mysql_close();
}
else
{
    mysql_select_db($DB_NAME,$CONN);
}
```

Login.php :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="Config/Checklogin.php">
   <input name="txtUsername" type="text"  id="txtUsername" autocomplete="off" />
   <input name="txtPassword" type="password"  id="txtPassword" />
   <p>Remember ME .</p><input name="chkRemember" id="chkRemember" type="checkbox"     /><
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Config/Checklogin.php :

```
session_start();
      include("Config.php");
if(!empty($_POST["txtUsername"])&& !empty($_POST["txtPassword"]))
{

        $User=$_POST["txtUsername"];
        $PASSWORD=$_POST["txtPassword"];
             $Remember=$_POST["chkRemember"];
            setSession($User,$PASSWORD,$Remember);
}
if(  (ctype_alnum($User))   ) 
{
      setSession($User,$PASSWORD,$Remember); // --> setSession is a function
}
else
{

header("Location:../Login.php");        
}
//------------------------ FUNCTION :
function setSession($YOURUSERNAME,$YOURPASSWORD,$Remember)
{


    /* ========================================================= */
    $sel="SELECT * FROM TBL_USERS WHERE USERNAME='".SAFE($YOURUSERNAME)."'".
    "AND PASSWORD= '".SAFE($YOURPASSWORD)."'";

    //=================================================



    $Result=QUERY($sel);
    $Row=mysql_num_rows($Result);

    if($Row==1)
    {
        if($Remember=='on')
        {
            setcookie("user", $YOURUSERNAME, time()+3600,"/");  // for an houre 
            header("location:../index.php");

        } 
        else if($Remember==NULL)
        {
                $_SESSION["user"]=$YOURUSERNAME;
                header("location:../index.php");
        }
    }
    else
    {
            header("location:../login.php");    
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Mohammad.Amin, may be i didn't explain correctly what i need to perform. In fact this code is to track sales not to login. Each affiliate has its own tracking code wich is passed though url '../?id=affiliate' so i need to pick this id and see if there's any affiliate registered in order to credit his/her commssion.  the reason i need to setup a cookie to setup a session is that i'll have  many affiliates promoting same products and pages.